# custom cc_toolchain used in bazel rule

Tags: build, bazel, riscv

I've been trying to write a bazel rule to wrap compiling for risc-v source files, does some other stuff, etc, but I've been having some trouble with getting a `CcToolchainInfo` provider.

I have a rule that works that looks like

```
rv_cc_toolchain_config = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
    attrs = {},
    provides = [CcToolchainConfigInfo],
)
```

in order to provide config info. I have the following in `toolchains/BUILD`:

```
load(":cc_toolchain_config.bzl", "rv_cc_toolchain_config")

package(default_visibility = ['//visibility:public'])


rv_cc_toolchain_config(name="rv_toolchain_cfg")


cc_toolchain(
    name='rv_toolchain',
    toolchain_identifier='rv-toolchain',
    toolchain_config=':rv_toolchain_cfg',
    all_files=':nofile',
    strip_files=':nofile',
    objcopy_files=':nofile',
    dwp_files=':nofile',
    compiler_files=':nofile',
    linker_files=':nofile',
)
```

This seems to all work fine; I then have my custom rule to compile with riscv:

```
def _compile_impl(ctx):
    deps = []
    cc_toolchain = find_cpp_toolchain(ctx)
    print(ctx.attr._cc_toolchain)
    compilation_contexts = [dep[CcInfo].compilation_context for dep in deps]
    print(type(cc_toolchain))
    feature_configuration = cc_common.configure_features( #fails here
        ctx = ctx,
        cc_toolchain = cc_toolchain,
        requested_features = ctx.features,  #currently does nothing
        unsupported_features = ctx.disabled_features,
    )




rv_compile = rule(
    _compile_impl,
    output_to_genfiles = True,
    attrs = {
        "srcs": attr.label_list(
            doc = "List of source files",
            mandatory = False,
            allow_files = [".cc", ".cpp", ".h", ".c"],
        ),
        "hdrs": attr.label_list(
            doc = "List of header files",
            allow_files = [".h"],
        ),
        "_cc_toolchain": attr.label(
            #default = Label("@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:current_cc_toolchain"),
            default = Label("//toolchains:rv_toolchain")
        ),
    },
    provides = [
        DefaultInfo,
        CcInfo,
    ],
    toolchains = [
        "@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type",
    ],
    fragments = ["cpp"]
)
```

Where I fail when trying to configure the toolchain because `cc_toolchain` is of type `ToolchainInfo` and not the required `CcToolchainInfo`. Does anyone have any insight on how to provide CcToolchainInfo within a rule? Or is there a better way of doing this? Documentation seems to go dark on this.

Answer (score 4):

Oops -- figured this out after trolling through github. Turns out the problem is directly referencing `cc_toolchain` is incorrect, and that CcToolchainInfo is provided via `cc_toolchain_suite`

updating `toolchains/BUILD` to look something like

```
load(":cc_toolchain_config.bzl", "rv_cc_toolchain_config")

package(default_visibility = ['//visibility:public'])


rv_cc_toolchain_config(name="rv_toolchain_cfg")


filegroup(name = 'empty')
cc_toolchain(
    name='rv_toolchain',
    toolchain_identifier='sanity-toolchain',
    toolchain_config=':rv_toolchain_cfg',
    all_files=':empty',
    strip_files=':empty',
    objcopy_files=':empty',
    dwp_files=':empty',
    compiler_files=':empty',
    linker_files=':empty',
)


cc_toolchain_suite(
    name='rv',
    toolchains={
        'darwin': ':rv_toolchain', #use whatever OS you need here... 
    }
)
```

and the rv compile rule to something like

```
rv_compile = rule(
    _compile_impl,
    output_to_genfiles = True,
    attrs = {
        "srcs": attr.label_list(
            doc = "List of source files",
            mandatory = False,
            allow_files = [".cc", ".cpp", ".h", ".c"],
        ),
        "hdrs": attr.label_list(
            doc = "List of header files",
            allow_files = [".h"],
        ),
        "_cc_toolchain": attr.label(
            #default = Label("@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:current_cc_toolchain"),
            default = Label("//toolchains:rv")
        ),
    },
    provides = [
        DefaultInfo,
        CcInfo,
    ],
    toolchains = [
        "@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type",
    ],
    fragments = ["cpp"]
)
```

works like a charm :) anyone reading this should also enable expirimental skylark cpp apis as well. if anyone knows how to make cc_toolchain_suite cpu agnostic, i'd love to hear it. cheers.